# Filtering tweets on a locally stored dataset

Tags: twitter, filtering, locally-abstract-type

I want to filter the most common/popular tweets (like the most retweeted ones) about Corona on a locally stored dataset.
But if I use:

```
# Extract tweets with a minimum of 100 retweets and 100 favorites
tweets_pop <- search_tweets("Corona min_retweets:100 AND min_faves:100")
```

It always tries to look on Twitter itself.

And with

```
filter (tweets, retweetCount > 100)
```

Or

```
top_n(retweetCount, 15)
```

Nothing happens

Comment: What did you do to store those tweets locally? It seems you are using a library that utilizes the Twitter API. Most APIs don't have the functionality of caching the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
filepath <- "path where the data is"
tweets <- readLines(filepath)
```

the libraries i loaded are:

```
library("tm")
library("SnowballC")
library("wordcloud")
library("RColorBrewer")
```

it shows me all the data in a second filesheet but I can't filter it.

The dataset would be this one:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Alx2bYJE2wF-gf4fDWhIKiiLTLIBVA?e=nNorm1